# severe malfunction: computer unusable(system program problem detected) 14.04, 32 bit

Tags: 14.04, malware

I boot up my computer and sign in and immediately the "system program problem detected" box pops up and i click send report, and then the computer shuts itself down.
My son was on a online game site and it asked him to update firefox and ever since then the computer has been acting up.  has anyone had a similar problem? could it be a malware infection?

Answer (score 0):

If it were a malware infection, that would be the first time I've seen it, but there's a first time for everything so lets run with that assumption for now.  Let's assume that firefox has somehow run amuck, the only way I can imagine that it is preventing the computer from booting normally is if you have put firefox in your startup sequence.  If so, here's the solution:

All you need to do is login to another account in which firefox is not in your startups sequence and then uninstall firefox.  If it is no longer there, it cannot misbehave.